# Showing continuity of Markov processes

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, markov-process

Consider the following concepts of continuity of Markov transition functions:

*Let $(P_t)$ be a Markov transition function on $(E, \mathcal{E})$ and let $H$ a set of bounded, real-valued $\mathcal{E}$-measurable functions. $(P_t)$ is called*

**strongly continuous** on $H$ if for each $f \in H$ we have

$$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} || P_tf-P_0f||_{\infty} = 0$$

**weakly continuous** on $H$ if for each $f \in H$ and $x \in E$ we have

$$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} (P_tf)(x) = (P_0f)(x).$$

I'm struggling to show these properties for given transition functions. Especially ways of showing strong continuity seem very hard to me since I can't think of theorems for showing this kind uniform convergence in a probabilistic setting.**What are comon ways to prove these properties? What are some examples for transition functions fulfilling or not fulfilling these properties?**

Comment: Your question is pretty broad... could you be a tad more specific what kind of transition functions you have in mind?